# "Дивитися за" і "дивитися на" - різниця

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми, прийменники

Нещодавно слухав різні переклади твору "Дари Волхвів". У творі зустрілося речення:

> She stood by the window and looked out dully at a gray cat walking a
>   gray fence in a gray backyard.

І перекладач зробив наступний перклад:

> Вона стояла біля вікна і **дивилася за** сірою кішкою, яка гуляла по
>   сірому заборі на сірому подвір'ї

Деякі з присутніх заявили, що словосполучення "дивитися за" в цьому реченні означає "Доглядати за кимось" і воно вжито неправильно. Натомість потрібно було використати словоспослучення "дивитися на".

Цікавить чи справді "дивитися за" означає лише "доглядати за кимось" (бо судячи з [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/dyvytysja) таке значення дійсно є) і чи може воно бути синонімом до "дивитися на когось". Наведу приклади перекладів творів, де "дивитися за" означає "дивитися на когось/щось":

**Чак Поланік "[Виправний день](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=jjmCDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT452&lpg=PT452&dq=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%22&source=bl&ots=tm0oWuMoub&sig=ACfU3U0bFrVQmy7MIHMfPuN9TxF0szeWkg&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDlLqmmcbhAhVhmYsKHQQVCmIQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%22&f=false)"**

> Він **дивився за** світлом фар у темряві

**Грей Алекс "[Одержимість](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=EU2HDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT235&lpg=PT235&dq=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%22&source=bl&ots=f3YC7XutIB&sig=ACfU3U1R0nsEpW4ctjIgYCxWk99UNVUO6A&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDlLqmmcbhAhVhmYsKHQQVCmIQ6AEwCXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%22&f=false)"**:

... він **дивився за** реакцією Анни.

Comment: Мені здається, що приклад "Він дивився за світлом фар у темряві" не коректний, судячи з контексту автор мав на увазі "він дивився у напрямку світла фар" а не те що він дивився на саме світло фар.

Comment: У моєму мовному середовищі "дивитися за кимось/чимось", окрім "наглядати", має також значення "спостерігати". Ймовірно, оскільки це значення не згадане у СУМі, воно є діалектним. Тим не менше, воно гарно пасує до поданих вище прикладів.